# Как запретить отправку формы contact form 7 при определенных условиях?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Есть сайт на **wordpress** с формой обратной связи *contact form 7*
Мне необходимо при определенных условиях заблокировать отправку формы.
Для этой цели задействую фильтр skip mail, который прописываю в *functions.php*

```
function my_skip_mail($skip_mail, $contact_form) {
    if( /* your condition */ )
        $skip_mail = true; // true skips sending the email
    return $skip_mail; 
}
add_filter('wpcf7_skip_mail','my_skip_mail');
```

Делаю проверку, проверка проходит (отслеживаю это var_dump), но письмо всё равно отправляется.
Не помогает также прописать параметр *skip_mail* в дополнительных полях самой формы.

Как работает skip_mail, если не на блокировку отправки писем? Как отменить отправку письма при определённых условиях?

**UDP** всё оказалось интереснее! Письмо как будто отправляется с сообщением *"Спасибо за Ваше сообщение. Оно успешно отправлено."* и срабатыванием проверки `wpcf7mailsent`, но реально адресату оно не доходит. А вот если отключить фильтр, то доходит.. А как можно проверить сработал **skip** или нет и вместо вывода сообщения об успешной отправке написать ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю на свои же вопросы:

1. Как отменить отправку письма при определённых условиях?
   Как дал ответ выше @KAGG Design , этот фильтр отменяет отправку писем

`add_filter( 'wpcf7_skip_mail','my_skip_mail', PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );`

2. А как можно проверить сработал skip или нет и вместо вывода сообщения об успешной отправке написать ошибка?
   Прописать внутри фильтра `wpcf7_skip_mail`

   `add_filter("wpcf7_feedback_response", function ($response) { $response["status"] = "mail_sent_ng"; $response["message"] = "Ошибка"; return $response; }, PHP_INT_MAX);`

и вернуть `return true;`

Answer (score 2):

Я посмотрел код CF7 - всё верно вы делаете. Скорее всего, где-то ещё задан фильтр `wpcf7_skip_mail`, и он возвращает `false`. Попробуйте поднять приоритет фильтра

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_skip_mail','my_skip_mail', PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
```

И да, вы обязательно должны указывать кол-во передаваемых в фильтр аргументов, если это не 1.

Comment: всё оказалось интереснее! Письмо как будто отправляется с сообщением "Спасибо за Ваше сообщение. Оно успешно отправлено." и срабатыванием проверки `wpcf7mailsent`, но реально адресату оно не доходит. А вот если отключить фильтр, то доходит.. А как можно проверить сработал `skip` или нет и вместо вывода сообщения об успешной отправке написать ошибка?